# SchemaFields not working in load_table_from_dataframe call (Python, BigQuery)

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am attempting to load a Pandas dataframe into BigQuery using the `load_table_from_dataframe` functionality described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe).

In some cases, a specific column in the dataframe whose purpose is to hold datetime-types may be complety empty/null.

In order to prevent the misinterpretation of this null column, I am using a LoadJobConfig [schema](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig#google_cloud_bigquery_job_LoadJobConfig_schema) to ensure that this column is loaded as a `DATETIME` column containing nulls.

However, when I check the table following the load job in BigQuery, I can see that it has been loaded as a column of `INT64` type.

How can I ensure that this column is loaded as `DATETIME` type, even if the column is empty?

Here is my code:

```
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField(
                name="created", 
                field_type="DATETIME", 
                mode="NULLABLE"
            ), 
            bigquery.SchemaField(
                name="ended", 
                field_type="DATETIME", 
                mode="NULLABLE"
            )
        ]
    )

    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(gcp_project)

    table_path = f"{gcp_project}.{dataset}.{table_name}"

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=to_df, 
        destination=table_path,
        job_config=job_config
    )
```